# Error while uploading category image

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.6

When I try to upload an image in a category I am getting below error.

[image]

The issue I found is that the function in the file 'vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\ImageUploader.php' `public function saveFileToTmpDir($fileId)` is called two times. One with the parameter 'image' and then with the parameter 'thumb_nail'. The error happens when it is called with the parameter 'thumb_nail'. I couldn't find where that function is getting called. It is supposed to be called from the controller 'vendor\magento\module-catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Image\Upload.php'. But when I comment out the code in the controller it is still being called. And it is supposed to be called one time with the parameter 'image'

Comment: Into the default magento, this functionality works fine to think you have installed any third-party extension, and this extension overrides any image upload class that's why this error happens please check first into your extension list.

Comment: Yes. The theme was overriding that function. Thank you!